# How to save a filtered file in a function?

Tags: r, function

I am writing the following function:

```
filter.na <- function(x, threshold) {
    x[(rowSums(is.na(x)))/ncol(x) > threshold,]
}
```

I would like to save the filtered file as csv. So my idea is to create a new function parameter in order to let it save the filtered file, let's call it `csv.save` where the default value should be `null`

I don't know how to go ahead, can anyone help?

Comment: Functions should do one thing only (this is known as *single responsibility principle*). It’s therefore not a good idea to create a function that filters *and* stores data.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this is what you want.

```
filter.na <- function(x, threshold, csv.save = FALSE, filename = NULL) {
  y <- x[(rowSums(is.na(x)))/ncol(x) > threshold,]
  if (csv.save){
    write.csv(y, filename)
  }
  return(y)
}
```

And if you want to save a csv file, set `csv.save to TRUE` and provide a file name for the `filename` argument when you use the function, such as the example below.

```
x <- data.frame(a = c(NA, NA, 1),
                b = c(1, 2, 3), 
                c = c(NA, NA, 2))

filter.na(x, 0, csv.save = TRUE, "test.csv")
```